# Future Class triggering two emails instead of one when a record is updated

Tags: apex, trigger, email, future

When i create a new record and update it my future class is sending two mails to user and after that when i update the same record then it sends one mail. Problem i need to send only one mail to user. Below is my code.

```
trigger SendReporttoSE on Sample_Lab_Requests_New__c (before update) {

Set<Id> sampleRequestIds = new Set<Id>(); 
List<Sample_Lab_Requests_New__c > sampleRequests = new List<Sample_Lab_Requests_New__c >(); 
Map<Id, List<Sample_Result__c >> mapSRIdResultsMap = new Map<Id, List<Sample_Result__c >>();
Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();

Map<Id,User> userMap = new Map<Id,User>();
List<User> userList= new List<User>();

for(Sample_Lab_Requests_New__c newSR : Trigger.new) {
    /*
    if(Trigger.isInsert && newSR.SE_Inspect_before_ship_yes_or_no__c == 'Yes' && newSR.Status__c == 'Ready For Inspection' ){
        sampleRequestIds.add(newSR.Id);
        ownerIds.add(newSr.ownerId);
        sampleRequests.add(newSR);
    }
    */
    
    if(trigger.isUpdate &&  newSR.SE_Inspect_before_ship_yes_or_no__c == 'Yes' && newSR.Status__c == 'Ready For Inspection' ) { 
        sampleRequestIds.add(newSR.Id);  
        ownerIds.add(newSr.ownerId);               
        sampleRequests.add(newSR);            
    }     
    System.debug('sampleRequests***' +sampleRequests);
    system.debug('@@@@@ sampleRequestIds'+sampleRequestIds);
}

// map of Sample Request Id and List of Sample Results
if(sampleRequestIds.size() > 0) {  
    List<Sample_Result__c> sampleResultList = [SELECT id,Name,Additional_Comments_CIJ__c,Additional_Comments_GRAPHICS__c,Additional_Comments_LCM__c,Additional_Comments_Laser__c,Additional_Comments_TTO__c,Additional_Comments_Wolke__c,Sample_Lab_Request__c from Sample_Result__c where Sample_Lab_Request__c IN: sampleRequestIds ];
    for(Sample_Result__c sre: sampleResultList) {
            if(String.isNotBlank(sre.Sample_Lab_Request__c)) {
                if(!mapSRIdResultsMap.containsKey(sre.Sample_Lab_Request__c)) {
                    mapSRIdResultsMap.put(sre.Sample_Lab_Request__c, new List<Sample_Result__c >());
            }
            mapSRIdResultsMap.get(sre.Sample_Lab_Request__c).add(sre);   
            System.debug('mapSRIdResultsMap***' +mapSRIdResultsMap);             
        }   
    }    
    userList = [SELECT id,Email,Name from User where Id IN: ownerIds];  
    
    System.debug('userList ***' +userList );       
}

if(userList.size() >0){
    for(User u:userList){
        userMap.put(u.Id,u);    
    }
}
// trigger the email
if(mapSRIdResultsMap.size() > 0 && userMap.size() >0) {
    System.debug('Inside***');
    for(Sample_Lab_Requests_New__c newSR : sampleRequests ) {
        System.debug('newSR.Id***' +newSR.Id);
        System.debug('mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)***' +mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id));
        if(mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)  != null){
            System.debug('userMap.get(newSR.ownerId).Email****' +userMap.get(newSR.ownerId).Email);
            System.debug('mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)****' +mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id));
            GeneratePDFandSendEmail.createContentandSendEmail(newSR.Name,newSR.Account_Name__c,newSR.Sample_Lab_Number__c,newSR.Id,userMap.get(newSR.ownerId).Email,userMap.get(newSR.ownerId).Name,mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)[0].Id, mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)[0].Name, mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)[0].Additional_Comments_CIJ__c,mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)[0].Additional_Comments_GRAPHICS__c,mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)[0].Additional_Comments_LCM__c,mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)[0].Additional_Comments_Laser__c,mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)[0].Additional_Comments_TTO__c,mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)[0].Additional_Comments_Wolke__c,newSR.QC_Inspection_Results__c);
        }
    }
}
    
}
```

Future class

```
public class GeneratePDFandSendEmail{

@Future(callout=true)
public static void createContentandSendEmail(String sampleRequestName,String Account,String SampleNumber,Id 
                                             SampleRequestId,String srOwnerEmail,String srOwnerName,
                                             Id sampleResultId,String sampleResultName,String addCommCIJ,
                                             String addCommGRAPHICS,String addCommLCM,String addCommLaser,
                                             String addCommTTO,String addCommWolke,String qCInspectionResults){

    PageReference pdf1 = Page.ResultReportPage;
    // add parent id to the parameters for standardcontroller
    pdf1.getParameters().put('id',sampleResultId);
    system.debug('Check123'+pdf1);        
    
    //PageReference pdf2 = Page.SR_Attachments;
    // add parent id to the parameters for standardcontroller
    //pdf2.getParameters().put('id',sampleResultId);

    
    // the contents of the attachment from the pdf
    Blob body1;
    //Blob body2;

    try {    
        // returns the output of the page as a PDF
        System.debug('pdf1***' +pdf1 );
        test.isRunningTest();
        body1 = pdf1.getContent();
        System.debug('body1***' +body1 );
        
        //body2 = pdf2.getContent();
        //System.debug('body2***' +body2);
        
        String sfdcBaseURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
        
        List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> allAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
        
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach1 = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attach1.setContentType('application/pdf');
        attach1.setFileName(sampleResultName+'.pdf');
        attach1.setInline(false);
        attach1.Body = body1;
        allAttachments.add(attach1);
        
       /* Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach2 = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attach1.setContentType('application/pdf');
        attach2.setFileName('All_Images'+'.pdf');
        attach2.setInline(false);
        attach2.Body = body2;
        allAttachments.add(attach2);*/
        
        if(sampleResultId != null){
            if(getObject(sampleResultId) != null){
                List<sObject> sObjectStore = getObject(sampleResultId);
                System.debug('sObjectStore***' +sObjectStore);
               // attachmentClassPDF(sObjectStore[0].Id);
               Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
               for(sObject s:sObjectStore){
                   parentIds.add(s.Id);
               }
               
                String additionalComments;
                if(String.valueOf(sObjectStore[0]).startsWith('CIJ')){
                    CIJ_Test_Result__c cijTestResult = (CIJ_Test_Result__c)sObjectStore[0];
                    if(cijTestResult != null && cijTestResult.Additional_Comments__c  != null){
                        additionalComments = cijTestResult.Additional_Comments__c;
                    }
                    else{
                        additionalComments = '';
                    }
                }
                if(String.valueOf(sObjectStore[0]).startsWith('GRAPHICS')){
                    GRAPHICS_Test_Result__c graphicsTestResult = (GRAPHICS_Test_Result__c)sObjectStore[0];
                    if(graphicsTestResult != null && graphicsTestResult.Additional_Comments__c  != null ){
                        additionalComments = graphicsTestResult.Additional_Comments__c;
                    }
                    else{
                        additionalComments = '';
                    }
                }
                if(String.valueOf(sObjectStore[0]).startsWith('LCM')){
                    LCM_Test_Result__c lcmTestResult = (LCM_Test_Result__c)sObjectStore[0];
                    if(lcmTestResult != null && lcmTestResult.Additional_Comments__c  != null ){
                        additionalComments = lcmTestResult.Additional_Comments__c;
                    }
                    else{
                        additionalComments = '';
                    }
                }
                if(String.valueOf(sObjectStore[0]).startsWith('Laser')){
                    Laser_Test_Result__c laserTestResult = (Laser_Test_Result__c)sObjectStore[0];
                    if(laserTestResult != null && laserTestResult.Additional_Comments__c  != null ){
                        additionalComments = laserTestResult.Additional_Comments__c;
                    }
                    else{
                        additionalComments = '';
                    }
                }
                if(String.valueOf(sObjectStore[0]).startsWith('LPA')){
                    LPA_Test_Result__c lpaTestResult = (LPA_Test_Result__c)sObjectStore[0];
                    if(lpaTestResult != null && lpaTestResult.Additional_Comments__c  != null ){
                        additionalComments = lpaTestResult.Additional_Comments__c;
                    }
                    else{
                        additionalComments = '';
                    }
                }
                if(String.valueOf(sObjectStore[0]).startsWith('TIJ')){
                    TIJ_Test_Result__c tijTestResult = (TIJ_Test_Result__c)sObjectStore[0];
                    if(tijTestResult != null && tijTestResult.Additional_Comments__c  != null  ){
                        additionalComments = tijTestResult.Additional_Comments__c;
                    }
                    else{
                        additionalComments = '';
                    }
                }
                if(String.valueOf(sObjectStore[0]).startsWith('TTO')){
                    TTO_Test_Result__c ttoTestResult = (TTO_Test_Result__c)sObjectStore[0];
                    if(ttoTestResult != null){
                        additionalComments = ttoTestResult.Additional_Comments__c;
                    }
                    else{
                        additionalComments = '';
                    }
                }
                
                for (Attachment a : attachmentClassPDF(parentIds)){
                    Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
                    efa.setFileName(a.Name);
                    efa.setBody(a.Body);
                    if(a.ContentType.equalsIgnoreCase('pdf')){
                        efa.setContentType('application/pdf');
                    }
                    if(a.ContentType.equalsIgnoreCase('JPG')){
                        efa.setContentType('image/jpg');
                    }
                    if(a.ContentType.equalsIgnoreCase('JPEG')){
                        efa.setContentType('image/jpeg');
                    }
                    if(a.ContentType.equalsIgnoreCase('BMP')){
                        efa.setContentType('image/bmp');
                    }
                    if(a.ContentType.equalsIgnoreCase('gif')){
                        efa.setContentType('image/gif');
                    }
                    if(a.ContentType.equalsIgnoreCase('TIF')){
                        efa.setContentType('image/tiff');
                    }
                    if(a.ContentType.equalsIgnoreCase('PNG')){
                        efa.setContentType('image/png');
                    }
                    if(a.ContentType.equalsIgnoreCase('PSD')){
                        efa.setContentType('image/psd');
                    }
                    if(a.ContentType.equalsIgnoreCase('PSPIMAGE')){
                        efa.setContentType('image/pspimage');
                    }
                    if(a.ContentType.equalsIgnoreCase('thm')){
                        efa.setContentType('image/thm');
                    }
                    if(a.ContentType.equalsIgnoreCase('yuv')){
                        efa.setContentType('image/yuv');
                    }
                    allAttachments.add(efa);            
                }
                
                if(qCInspectionResults != null && qCInspectionResults .contains('May Require SE Approval') ){  
                    string strSubject='(' + SampleNumber+ ') for '+ Account +'';      
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    mail.setUseSignature(false);
                    mail.setToAddresses(new String[] { srOwnerEmail});
                   // mail.setSubject('Approval Required for Sample Request '+sampleRequestName  +SampleNumber);
                     mail.setSubject('Approval Requested -- Sample Request '+strSubject);
                    mail.setHtmlBody('<image id="Logo" src="https://test.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=01580000000kAqN&oid=00D80000000d2pY"/>'+'<br/><br/>'+'<br/><br/>'+'Hello'+' '+srOwnerName+','+'<br/><br/>'+' Sample Request :'+SampleNumber+' '+'</b>'+' '+'<a href='+'"'+Label.SalesforceURL+'/'+SampleRequestId+'"'+'>'+' '+sampleRequestName+'</a>'+' is ready for you to review. If you are unable to review these by 4PM CT tomorrow, the lab will assume results are acceptable. Please <b><u>Call</u></b> the lab directly if any questions or concerns.'+'<br/><br/>'+'<b>'+'Technician Comments:'+'</b>'+' '+'<br/>"'+additionalComments+'"' +'<br/><br/>'+' Please review all attached images and Sample Reports.'+'<br/><br/>'+'Problem Viewing Images? '+'<a href='+'"'+Label.SalesforceURL+'/apex/SR_Attachments?id='+sampleResultId+'"'+'>Click Here! '+'</a>'+'to see all full scale images'+'<br/><br/>'+'Click here '+'<a href='+'"'+Label.SiteUrl+'/SetSampleRequestApproved?id='+SampleRequestId+'"'+'> '+''+'</a>'+'to Approve the request'+'<br/><br/>'+'<b>'+'Questions? Call 1-630-694-2969'+'</b>'+'<br/><br/>'+'Click here'+'<a href='+'"'+Label.SiteUrl+'/SampleRequestApproval?id='+SampleRequestId+'"'+'> '+'  '+'</a>'+'to Reject the request'+'<br/><br/>'+'<br/><br/>'+'<p style="font-family:Calibri;font-size: 16px;line-height:8px">'+'Thank You,'+'<br/><br/>'+'Applications Lab | Applications Lab Team'+'<br/><br/>'+'Test Technologies Inc. | www.Test.com'+'<br/><br/>'+'Ph: +1-XXXXXXXXXX | applicationslab@Test.com'+'<br/><br/>'+'Test'+'</p>');
                    mail.setFileAttachments(allAttachments ); 
                    System.debug('mail***' +mail);
                    // Send the email
                    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (VisualforceException e) {
        body1 = Blob.valueOf(sampleRequestName);
        system.debug('@@@@@@Exception: '+e.getMessage());
        system.debug('@@@@body1:'+body1);
    }
}

public static List<Attachment> attachmentClassPDF(Set<Id> theId){

    List<Attachment> attachList;
    String pdfId;
    List<String> pdfs= new List<String>();
    boolean displayImage = false;
    
    if( theId != null ){
        attachList=[Select id,name,Description,ContentType,IsPrivate ,ParentId,Body, BodyLength from Attachment where  ParentId IN: theId and ( name LIKE '%pdf%' or name LIKE '%JPG%' or name LIKE '%JPEG%' or name LIKE '%BMP%' or name LIKE '%gif%' or name LIKE '%TIF%' or name LIKE '%PNG%' or name LIKE '%PSD%' or name LIKE '%PSPIMAGE%'  or name LIKE '%thm%'  or name LIKE '%yuv%' ) ]; 
    }  
    return attachList;
}

public static List<sObject> getObject(Id sampleResultId){
    
    List<Id> idStore = new List<Id>();
    
    List<CIJ_Test_Result__c> cijTestResult = [SELECT id,Additional_Comments__c from CIJ_Test_Result__c where Sample_Result__c =: sampleResultId order by createddate ASC];
    if(cijTestResult != null && cijTestResult.size() >0){
        return cijTestResult;
    }
    
    List<GRAPHICS_Test_Result__c> graphicsTestResult = [SELECT id,Additional_Comments__c from GRAPHICS_Test_Result__c where Sample_Result__c =: sampleResultId order by createddate ASC ];
    if(graphicsTestResult != null && graphicsTestResult.size() >0){
        return graphicsTestResult;
    }
    
    List<LASER_Test_Result__c> laserTestResult = [SELECT id,Additional_Comments__c from LASER_Test_Result__c where Sample_Result__c =: sampleResultId order by createddate ASC ];
    if(laserTestResult != null && laserTestResult.size() >0){
        return laserTestResult;
    }
    
    List<LCM_Test_Result__c> lcmTestResult = [SELECT id,Additional_Comments__c from LCM_Test_Result__c where Sample_Result__c =: sampleResultId order by createddate ASC ];
    if(lcmTestResult != null && lcmTestResult.size() >0){
        return lcmTestResult;
    }
    
    List<LPA_Test_Result__c> lpaTestResult = [SELECT id,Additional_Comments__c from LPA_Test_Result__c where Sample_Result__c =: sampleResultId order by createddate ASC ];
    if(lpaTestResult != null && lpaTestResult.size() >0){
        return lpaTestResult;
    }
    
    List<TIJ_Test_Result__c> tijTestResult = [SELECT id,Additional_Comments__c from TIJ_Test_Result__c where Sample_Result__c =: sampleResultId order by createddate ASC ];
    if(tijTestResult != null && tijTestResult.size() >0){
        return tijTestResult;
    }
    
    List<TTO_Test_Result__c> ttoTestResult = [SELECT id,Additional_Comments__c from TTO_Test_Result__c where Sample_Result__c =: sampleResultId order by createddate ASC ];
    if(ttoTestResult != null && ttoTestResult.size() >0){
        return ttoTestResult;
    }
    
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Do you have a processbuilder, workflow /another trigger on it?

Comment: Hey, @goutham, can you describe the first scenario a little more -- the one where the result is two emails?  It sounds like it's sending two emails when you initially insert the record, but since your trigger only fires on update, I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue appears to me to be one of recursion. Here's what I recommend:

First, create a class to hold a boolean to use for recursion detection as below:

```
Public Class TriggerHelper{

public static boolean firstRun = true;

}
```

**Note:** The boolean MUST be in a separate class. It cannot be located on your trigger or in a trigger helper class if it's to work!

I've removed the code in your trigger that had "isInsert" since it was commented out. I'm assuming you likely had either "before insert" or "after insert" in your trigger definition at some point since your trigger only says "before update" at this point in time. Regardless, the way it's written it could easily run both before update and after update.

Using the trigger contexts of `isInsert` and `isUpdate` doesn't specify the complete context for the trigger's code. In either case, those could be either `isBefore` or `isAfter`. Any workflow could potentially cause the trigger to execute again causing the `isUpdate` code to run twice.

Now, modify your code as follows:

```
trigger SendReporttoSE on Sample_Lab_Requests_New__c (before update) {

Set<Id> sampleRequestIds = new Set<Id>(); 
List<Sample_Lab_Requests_New__c > sampleRequests = new List<Sample_Lab_Requests_New__c >(); 
Map<Id, List<Sample_Result__c >> mapSRIdResultsMap = new Map<Id, List<Sample_Result__c >>();
Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();

Map<Id,User> userMap = new Map<Id,User>();
List<User> userList= new List<User>();

    // Line below tests for value of firstRun boolean and that trigger is BeforeUpdate     
    if(TriggerHelper.firstRun && trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isBefore){
        // Set value of firstRun variable to false to prevent code from running again
        TriggerHelper.firstRun = false;

        for(Sample_Lab_Requests_New__c newSR : Trigger.new) {

            if(newSR.SE_Inspect_before_ship_yes_or_no__c == 'Yes' && newSR.Status__c == 'Ready For Inspection' ) { 
            sampleRequestIds.add(newSR.Id);  
            ownerIds.add(newSr.ownerId);               
            sampleRequests.add(newSR);            
            }     
        System.debug('sampleRequests***' +sampleRequests);
        system.debug('@@@@@ sampleRequestIds'+sampleRequestIds);
        }

        // map of Sample Request Id and List of Sample Results
        if(sampleRequestIds.size() > 0) {  
            List<Sample_Result__c> sampleResultList = [SELECT id,Name,Additional_Comments_CIJ__c,Additional_Comments_GRAPHICS__c,Additional_Comments_LCM__c,Additional_Comments_Laser__c,Additional_Comments_TTO__c,Additional_Comments_Wolke__c,Sample_Lab_Request__c from Sample_Result__c where Sample_Lab_Request__c IN: sampleRequestIds ];
            for(Sample_Result__c sre: sampleResultList) {
                if(String.isNotBlank(sre.Sample_Lab_Request__c)) {
                    if(!mapSRIdResultsMap.containsKey(sre.Sample_Lab_Request__c)) {
                        mapSRIdResultsMap.put(sre.Sample_Lab_Request__c, new List<Sample_Result__c >());
                    }
                    mapSRIdResultsMap.get(sre.Sample_Lab_Request__c).add(sre);   
                    System.debug('mapSRIdResultsMap***' +mapSRIdResultsMap);             
                }   
            }    
            userList = [SELECT id,Email,Name from User where Id IN: ownerIds];  

            System.debug('userList ***' +userList );       
        }

        if(userList.size() >0){
            for(User u:userList){
                userMap.put(u.Id,u);    
            }
        }
        // trigger the email
        if(mapSRIdResultsMap.size() > 0 && userMap.size() >0) {
            System.debug('Inside***');
            for(Sample_Lab_Requests_New__c newSR : sampleRequests ) {
                System.debug('newSR.Id***' +newSR.Id);
                System.debug('mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)***' +mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id));
                if(mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)  != null){
                    System.debug('userMap.get(newSR.ownerId).Email****' +userMap.get(newSR.ownerId).Email);
                    System.debug('mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)****' +mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id));
                    GeneratePDFandSendEmail.createContentandSendEmail(newSR.Name,newSR.Account_Name__c,newSR.Sample_Lab_Number__c,newSR.Id,userMap.get(newSR.ownerId).Email,userMap.get(newSR.ownerId).Name,mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)[0].Id, mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)[0].Name, mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)[0].Additional_Comments_CIJ__c,mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)[0].Additional_Comments_GRAPHICS__c,mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)[0].Additional_Comments_LCM__c,mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)[0].Additional_Comments_Laser__c,mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)[0].Additional_Comments_TTO__c,mapSRIdResultsMap.get(newSR.Id)[0].Additional_Comments_Wolke__c,newSR.QC_Inspection_Results__c);
                }
            }
        }
    } // end of test for firstRun and BeforeUpdate
}
```

The code causes the `firstRun` boolean to change from `true` to `false` the first time it executes. This prevents the trigger from entering that section of code a 2nd time. Consequently, your @future method will only be called once in the same execution context.

Comment: N.B. using simple static Boolean will prevent the logic from executing on any transaction with more than 200 records (such as Bulk API)

Comment: @cropredy Not in a simple trigger where the boolean is called from a separate class. If the boolean were on the trigger, I'd agree with you. Ditto if it were on a helper class.

Comment: Hmm - you define `firstRun` as an instance variable but reference it as a static variable. Once a static variable is set to value V, it retains that value across trigger contexts (e.g. DML update of 201 records is two trigger contexts within one transaction)

Comment: My bad. That was an omission on not including static in the definition. Have corrected the oversight. Thanks for spotting it. The 201 records should be in the same execution context as one transaction for the trigger.

Comment: if the transaction is an update of 201+ records, the line:`if(TriggerHelper.firstRun && trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isBefore){` will be executed twice in one transaction - once for records 1-200, and again for records 201+.  The first execution will set `firstRun` to false and it will stay that value when the aforementioned line is executed again for records 201+ - thus the line `for ... : Trigger.new` will not execute on records 201+

Comment: Ok, He needs to either refactor the code again and move the logic & firstRun boolean detection to a helper class or use a trigger framework if he wants it handle recursion for more than 200 records. :P